# Can VMD change its cartoon representation for secondary structure according to trajectories?

Tags: proteins, protein-structure, structure-prediction

I am using `VMD` to visualise the secondary structure of protein.

The trajectories are from my Gromacs simulation. Firstly I use `File - New Molecule...` to load the `protein.gro` file. Secondly I use `File - Load Data into Molecule...` to load my `protein.xtc` trajectories.

Then I use `Cartoon` to visulise the structure. As I drag the time frames, all the secondary structures (e.g. alpha-helix, beta-sheet) keep the same. But I am pretty sure some of them are changing, as I look into the `Timeline` analysis for secondary structure.

So how to use `VMD` to see the secondary structures at different time frames?

Thanks a lot for @Stefan's help! It finally works! So follow Stefan's guide, and replace the `molid` with the number under the `ID` in the `VMD Main`.

Comment: I see this was asked first on bioinformatics.SE: https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/3432

Comment: yes, because no one answer it.

Comment: And could you please tell me, where is rule that I cannot ask a repeated question in two sites? @marcin

Comment: @lanselibai it is all over the place, check [this answer](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/620) by the cofounder of SE for instance.  And it's not a rule per se, but its generally preferred that you tailor your questions to the audience of the site you're posting on.

Comment: I understand the necessity to ask only in one place. But because there is not a clear boundary line regarding my VMD software issue, I feel it can fit both sites. So, it would be better if there is an explicit definition of where my question should be posted.

Comment: @lanselibai: "Animating the secondary structure" http://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Research/vmd/vmd-1.3/ug/node256.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Martin pointed out, VMD doesn't update secondary structure content over the course of an MD trajectory. You can easily do this in VMD by using the SSCache script:

http://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Research/vmd/script_library/scripts/sscache/sscache.tcl

I believe it ships with the newest versions of VMD, actually, but I'm not exactly sure; even if not, you can easily source it:

Extensions > Tk console (in the console, type `source Downloads/sscache.tcl` (or where ever you've saved the script)). Once you've sourced the script, the easiest thing to do would be to load your topology and trajectory and (in the Tk console) issue the command `start_sscache molid`, although I advise having a look at the examples and options in the script.

Comment: thank you very much. Both `source Downloads/sscache.tcl` and `start_sscache molid` could use. However, as I move along the time frame, I could not see any secondary structure (SS) change. I was using `Extensions` - `Analysis` - `Timeline`- `Calculate` - `Calc. Sec. Struct.` to visualise the SS, so I know the SS is definitely changing. So I wonder if the `sscache` is adopting the same algorithm as `Timeline` (which is `STRIDE`) for SS?

Comment: 'molid' in this example is just a substitute for your system's ID; you can see it under ID next to the number of atoms in the VMD main window. If your system is called 'myMolecules,' you issue start_sscache myMolecules in the Tk console (you have to issue source Downloads/sscache.tcl, of course)

Answer (score 1):

[Animating the secondary structure in VMD](http://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Research/vmd/vmd-1.3/ug/node256.html)

> The secondary structure definitions for the molecules in VMD don't
>   change during an animation but they can be made to do so with a trace
>   on the vmd_frame($molecule) Tcl variable. The simplest way is to call
>   **vmd_calculate_structure(molecule)** every time the frame changes . . .